# Filling voids in DEM SRTM 1-arc second using QGIS by resampling and inserting another DEM

Tags: qgis, srtm, void

I'd like to use the DEM SRTM 1-arc second (Version 4, 30m) from USGS for Europe. Unfortunately there are some voids. My idea is to fill those voids using the void-filled version 3 (90m) by resampling it to 30m and inserting the missing data in the version 4 DEM.

As I'm new to QGIS I don't know the proper steps. I already got a 30m map by reprojecting the dimensions times three but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do and I have no idea how to fill the voids afterwards.

Comment: Only about how to fill the voids... there are patch tools in QGIS Processing Toolbox. One is GRASS `r.patch` and another is SAGA `Patching` in Raster tools. My recommendation is SAGA tool (just because I have difficulty running r.patch).